# I have no idea why state updated like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just know that when using `useState`'s state is updated, fired component and its child components are also re-render. But when wrote this code , somehow update like this console log.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { ChildA } from './ChildA.jsx';
import { ChildB } from './ChildB.jsx';


function App() {
  console.log('Parent render!')
  const [countA, setCountA] = useState(0);
  const [countB, setCountB] = useState(0);

  const asyncJustReturnNull = async () => {
    return null;
  }

  const countUpDouble = () => {
    setCountA(countA + 1);
    asyncJustReturnNull().then(() => {
      setCountA(countA + 1);
      setCountB(countB + 1);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <button onClick={() => countUpDouble()}>
          Update A and B at the same time.
        </button>
        <ChildA />
        countA is {countA}
        <ChildB />
        countB is {countB}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

CodePen is below.
https://codepen.io/showgotagami/pen/qBaBveG

Comment: What is the question? The counter looks to increment normally?

Comment: What's your problem? "Update like this" means exactly what? What do you expect?

Comment: I this a question from a job interview?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was insufficient. I'd like to know that `setCountA` update is called two times, so `countA` is expected to be `2`, but `countA` is now 1. And about component rendering, why Parent Component render log step is called two times continuously ? I expected that useState's update is called 3 times, so Parent and each Children Components are re-rendered also 3 times.

Comment: > OrAssayag No, this is just demo code. I just investigated about useState and component rendering count, then I wondered about this.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call

```
setCountA(countA + 1);
justReturnNull().then(() => {
    setCountA(countA + 1);
    setCountB(countB + 1);
})
```

`countA` is going to have the same value (0 initially) both times it's called. That's because `setCountA` is actually async and won't immediately change the value of `countA`.

A way of better visualising this could be this:

```
const incrementA = () => {
    console.log(countA);
    setCountA(countA + 1);
}

const updateBoth = () => {
    incrementA();
    justReturnNull().then(() => {
        incrementA();
        setCountB(countB + 1);
    })
};
```

This way we no longer pass `countA` around.

Answer (score 0):

In one sentence :

```
"State Updates are Merged"
```

They occur simultaneously.